# Should I set lots of SESSION variables for a logged in user or not?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a login.php and create a session when the user's email and password matches, then I would create  SESSION varibles for further uses

```
<?php

require_once '../php_includes/db_connects.php';
require_once '../php_includes/core_includes.php';


if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pasw'])){
    $e=$mysqli->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['email']));

 $p=md5($mysqli->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['pasw'])));

    $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user_info` WHERE `email`='$e' AND `password`='$p' LIMIT 1");
     $result->num_rows;
    if($result->num_rows ==1){
        while($obj=$result->fetch_object())
         {
            $_SESSION['id']=$obj->id;
            $_SESSION['firstname']=$obj->firstname;
            $_SESSION['lastname']=$obj->lastname;
            $_SESSION['email']=$obj->email;
            $_SESSION['college']=$obj->college;
            $_SESSION['profile_pic']=$obj->profile_pic;

        }


    }


}

?>
```

It's good to keep lots of session varibles to hold the basic info of the logged in user, or just retrieve those info from database each time I use it? Like I need to use firstname 10 times then I would have to get info from the database 10 times?

Comment: You need to call `session_start()` before using `$_SESSION`

Comment: MD5 is not secure.  You need an iterated, salted, hash.

Comment: `htmlentities` is completely wrong here.

Comment: I have a session start on my core_includes.php, but thanks@Machavity

Comment: Why set a bunch of separate session variables rather than storing a single user object in session (i.e. `$_SESSION['user'] = $user =- $obj;`  That way you could just call like `$user->id`, `$user->email` throughout the rest of your code.

Comment: Yes, I have hear about that md5 is not secure enough, I probably may store the password as md5(first3_letetrs)+md5(TheRemain_letters) and store it in separate columns, can this work?@SLaks

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.5 or later, you can use [password_hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: No, there is a function for this: `password_hash()`. See http://de3.php.net/password_hash If you don't use PHP 5.5, the function has been rebuilt for PHP down to 5.3.7, I think. See https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: What do you mean $_SESSION['user'] = $user =- $obj, there is a negation sign right there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using `$_SESSION` to save some hassle in pulling data over and over. Since you have to pull the user record at login, it's a good idea to have it pull other data and then stick that into session variables.

I wouldn't use `while` to do your login, though. I would hope your system is smart enough to only allow one authentication for a given set of credentials.

Comment: To add on to your second paragraph:  The `if` statement checks for the number of rows returned to be equal to 1, which means the `while` loop will run exactly once. The `while` loop is completely unnecessary.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` is unnecessary either. You can't have two different users (represented by records) authenticate with the same credentials (unique index should prevent that on db side).

Answer (score 0):

I think if the user changed his username or his e-mail address, you will still have the old information in the session .
So I think it's better to fetch them every time you use it.

Comment: If the user updates their record, why can't you update the session at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

There is basically one major step in performance hit when it comes to sessions, and a minor one.

The major one is to use a session at all. PHP's session is built so that it does not allow parallel requests being executed, so there will be a noticable effect when using PHP sessions on a site which also uses plenty of AJAX requests. You cannot avoid using something like a session if you have to log the user into the site, but then you should know how to release the session lock as early as possible with `session_write_close()`.

The minor impact is that the more session data you have, the slower reading and writing these will get. Do not abuse the session to act as a cache, i.e. don't write HUGE amounts of data to it. Huge would be a serialized 100 KB and up of data. Your tiny bit of user info won't affect performance at all.